# Phase Margin and Damping Ratio Approximation

Tags: control-system, phase-margin, damping-factor

I have read in many texts that the closed loop system damping factor can be approximated as:

\$\Phi_m= 100 * \zeta\$

With \$\Phi_m\$ as the phase margin and \$\zeta\$ as the damping ratio.
The actual relation between the two is more complicated and I think requires numerical method to solve.

[image: Lengthy phase margin calculation]

How is the approximation made in a second order control system, and when is it valid to consider the approximation (what's the range of the phase margin)?

Comment: Do you have a link to the assertion?

Comment: It's a design ROT for systems that are, ostensibly, 2nd order, and should be treated as such.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can see when the approximation is good simply by plotting the two curves.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The mentioned approximation for the phase margin (100*damping factor) applies to a second order system only when the damping factor is smaller than 1/SQRT(2)=0.7071 or when the phase margin is smaller than app. 65 deg.
(Ref.: R.C. Dorf, Modern Control Systems, 6th edition, Addison-Wesley).